# Accessing 2 columns in a 2D list in python

Tags: csv, python-3.x

So I'm new to using 2D lists in python. Basically I have a huge excel file in csv format. I have stored all the cells into a list called matrix. However, I only need the information in columns 4 - 5. I tried using range for the 2D list, but it doesn't seem to work. The two columns contain customer IDs and a True statement, respectively. My main purpose is just to count how many times each customer ID appears and store it into another 2D array. I've only gotten this far:

```
with open('authlog_20140305-20140617.csv','r') as file:
    contents = csv.reader(file)
    matrix = list()
    for row in contents:
        matrix.append(row)

for item in matrix:   # what I want is so that I only read columns 4 - 5 in matrix
    for item2 in uniqueIDs:
        if(item != item2):
            item2.append(item)
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you are interested only in columns 4 and 5 numbered from 1, use 0-based indexes of the columns like this `matrix.append(row[3:4])`... but what is the true statement good for if you are only counting all rows with particular customer ID?

Comment: Actually all rows have a customer ID

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `uniqueIDs` is, but I assume it is a list or set, right?

This code:

```
for line in matrix:
```

is going to iterate over each line of your matrix. For you to see the 4th and 5th columns, you would just need to use `line[3]` for the 4th and `line[4]` for the 5th (remember that lists in python are 0 indexed).

After that you can do what you need with that information.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to have a leap of faith and assume that you need to count items in 4th column iff 5th column is equal to string "true" (or some other simple `if` condition):

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('authlog_20140305-20140617.csv','r') as file:
    contents = csv.reader(file)
    c = Counter(row[3] for row in contents if row[4]=='true')
print(dict(c))
```

see doc about [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions)

sample data:

```
1,2,3,4,true
1,2,3,4,true
1,2,3,5,true
1,2,3,5,false
```

output: `{'4': 2, '5': 1}`

Comment: Is collections part of the python library or do I have to download it?

Comment: Yes, `collections` is a part of the standard library. The answer even has a link to the docs.